# TI-83 Programming Question

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Would it be improper to ask a question about programming a TI-83 Graphing Calculator here? Or would it be better in StackOverflow.SE.

Comment: If it's a math question, math.stackexchange.com – if it's a coding question, somewhere else.

Comment: Support questions for a proprietary product (such as a Texas Instrument graphing calculator) are best addressed to the vendor, rather than to a StackExchange site.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I actually found a TI83 Question on StackOverflow.SE Thanks. I just thought since it was math software. Point taken I'll ask it there.